# Node.js (discord.js) code randomly stops working in the middle of nothing

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So currently, I am making a discord bot in Replit, discord.js. I want to make economy system, and the code is "cutted" in the middle, like there was written "return", but there isn't.

```
  else if (type === "cashadd") {
    let target = message.mentions.users.first();
    const amount = args.join(" ");
    if (!target) return message.channel.send("Please metion someone!")
______________________ <- here the code is "cutted"
    if (!amount) return message.channel.send("Please specify the amount of money you want to send!")
    if(isNaN(amount)) return message.channel.send("please enter a real number")
    let userBalance = await db.get(`wallet_${target}`)
    await db.set(`wallet_${target}`, userBalance + amount)
    message.channel.send(`You sent ${amount} money to ${target}`)
  }
```

full code: https://pastebin.com/eaStV20P
(I am using command handled from Imagine gaming play if it is somehow useful)

I tried to put an extra like of code saying "it works", I was thinking if it says it. It didn't.

Comment: Presumably `target` cannot be found, does the `message.channel.send` call result in a message being sent to the channel?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is because you never spliced the arguments `const type =  args.splice(integer).join(" ");`

Just using `const type = args.join(" ");` just adds a space in between each argument. Here's an example:

`let args = ["Testing","Lol","Xd"]` (this is just an example of what args would be, in your case, it would be the entirety of the command arguments)

Using `const type = args.join(" ");` would return string `"Testing Lol Xd"`, as you can see by using `console.log(type)`

Using `const type = args.splice(integer).join(" ")` would remove all arguments prior to the integer provided, so if you did `const type = args.splice(1).join(" ");` this would return as `"Lol Xd"`, since `0` is the very first argument in the string, "Lol" would be the second argument in the string, so it would be integer 1, and so on.

So, if you want it to work how you want it to, try using `args.splice(integer).join(" ");`

An example for your code would be, Assuming your command is "-eco", and "balance" being everything else inside of the array,
if you typed `"-eco balance"` in a channel, args would be something along the lines of;

`args = ["-eco", "balance"];` `"balance"` string  being the `type` constant/variable you are looking for,

Actual code for this example:

```
const type = args.splice(1).join(" ");
if(type.toLowerCase === "balance") {
...
} else if(...) { ...
```